# NP-complete language as a result of xoring two PTIME languages

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, xor

> We define xor operation on languages $L,M\subseteq \{0,1\}^*$:
>   $$L\oplus M = \{u\oplus v :|u|=|v|, u\in L, v\in M\}$$   $\oplus$ is
>   defined as xor on postions, for example:  $001\oplus 100=101$   Show
>   that there exist  languages $L,M\in PTIME$ such that $L\oplus M\in
>  NP complete$

It is hard to me. I have been thinking a lot about it. My intuition is:

Write the problem as equations system and reduce 3-SAT to it. But, I am not sure if it is ok and, if yes, how to solve it.

Comment: You don't need to reduce the 3SAT to $L\oplus M$ in order to prove $L\oplus M \in NP$. It is enough to show that $x\in L\oplus M$ is verifiable in polynomial time on a deterministic TM. However, the reduction of 3SAT to $L\oplus M$ would also imply $L\oplus M \in NP$, but the latter may be harder to demonstrate.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Now, try to solve it yourself. First show that if both $L$ and $M$ in $PTIME$ then $L\oplus M$ is in $NP$. This part is easy - you don't need to come up with a concrete $L$ and $M$. Then try to come up with concrete $L$ and $M$ such that an $NP$-complete (maybe 3SAT) problem is reduced to $L\oplus M$. That part is harder. If you get stuck you can post what you have done and where you have got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a rather difficult question. Here is one approach.

Every 3CNF on $n$ variables can be encoded as a binary string of length $8n^3$ (how?). Consider the following two languages:
$$
\begin{align*}
L_1 &= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{ xy0^{8n^3} : |x|=n, |y|=8n^3, \text{$x$ is an assignment satisfying the 3CNF $y$} \}, \\
L_2 &= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{ x0^{8n^3}y : |x|=n, |y|=8n^3, \text{$x$ is an assignment satisfying the 3CNF $y$} \}.
\end{align*}
$$
These two languages are clearly in P, and so their XOR is clearly in NP. However,
$$
(L_1 \oplus L_2) \cap \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{0^ny^2 : |y|=8n^3\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{0^n y^2 : |y|=8n^3, y \text{ is satisfiable}\},
$$
showing that $L_1 \oplus L_2$ is NP-complete.

Comment: Why $L_1$ is in PTIME ?  After all, in this way I can solve $\phi$ in 3CNF in P: $L_1= \{x : \text{$x$ is an assigment satisfying given $\phi$ 3CNF formula} \}$

Comment: Your example is a finite language and so in $\mathsf{P}$. In fact, it has a constant time algorithm. The algorithm reads the first $n$ bits on the tape, and then can immediately answer Yes or No.

Comment: I understand that my approach (below) is not ok, because finite languages are regular. However, your $L_1$ is thing that I don't understand it. I can't see how you can do it in PTIME.

Comment: You can check whether a truth assignment satisfies a formula in polynomial time.

Comment: I know it.  So, why can't we use similar language to your $L_1$ to solve in PTIME 3-SAT ?

Comment: Since my $L_1$ specifies the truth assignment, whereas in 3SAT we are not given a truth assignment.

Comment: So in your $L_1$ suppose that we have truth assigment, ?

Comment: It is easy to check whether a *given* truth assignment satisfies a formula (indeed, this is essentially why 3SAT is in NP). It is hard to check whether there *exists* a truth assignment satisfying a formula.

Comment: Why intersection is allowed here ? I can see that in result of intersection is set of all satisfable 3CNF formulas. Could you sum up your solution? I mean 2-3 sentences with key ideas ?

Comment: The solution is a bit sketchy on purpose, since it's a homework question.

Comment: Could this be simplified conceptually by choosing $L_1 = \bigcup \{xy :|x|=n,|y|=8n^3, x \text{ is an assignment satisfying the 3CNF } y\}$ 
and
$L_2= \bigcup \{x0^{8n^3}:|x|=n \}$. In that way $L_2$ just hides the assignment .

Comment: @HendrikJan Indeed! This is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I have other idea, I am not sure if it is correct:
Let $k$ will be number of clauses and $n=5$ number of variables.
I reduce $3-$SAT problem, for each clause $c_i=(x_1, x_3, \neg x_5)$ I create language $$L_i= \{1\{0,1\}\{0,1\}\{0,1\}\{0,1\},\{0,1\}\{0,1\}1\{0,1\}\{0,1\}, \{0,1\}\{0,1\}\{0,1\}\{0,1\}0 \}$$
So $L_i$ contains patterns which satisfy $c_i$. Of course $L_i\in P$.
Let $$L=L_1\cdot ...\cdot L_k$$, $$M=\{(\{0,1\}^n)^k\}$$
Hence, $M$ contains all possible assigments reapeted $k$ times.  Now, we can check if $0^{kn}$ belongs to $L\oplus M$ in order to check if given $3CNF$ formula is satisfable.  The meaning  is that $0^{kn}\in M$ does mean that each clause agree with some assigment (agreeing corresponds to satisfability)

Comment: The language $L \oplus M$ is finite, and so trivially in $\mathsf{P}$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus in 3SAT problem there are also finite numbers of assigments, however 3SAT is in NP. Where is the key ?

Comment: Your language $L \oplus M$ is finite. The language of satisfiable 3CNF is infinite. The key is that $L,M$ in your case depend on a formula. What you want is a single pair $L,M$ that would work for *all* formulas.

Comment: yes, but @HaskellFun has to take a formula $F$ and convert it to that problem. Why is it not ok?

Comment: @Carol The construction just doesn't work.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, I see that the construciton doesn't work. You said something different. Please explain because I was confused. Haskell Fun was trying to convert a **concrete graph** to another representation to use another problem to solve it. You said that  ". What you want is a single pair $L,M$ that would work for *all* formulas".

Comment: @Carol Haskell Fun tried to construct a reduction from an instance of 3SAT to a pair of languages, such that satisfiability of 3SAT is equivalent to some property of the pair of languages. I guess the idea is that NP-hardness is often proven by reduction from an NP-hard language. But this strategy is inappropriate here, since we are interested in the properties of a *specific* pair of languages, whereas the reduction creates a pair of languages *depending* on the instance.

Comment: So, if you want show reduction from NP-hard problem it is sufficient to get any instancy of problem and express it in another problem, yes?